# need to change labels and button text in application

Tags: c#, wpf, text, mvvm

I am using WPF. In my application, i need to change the language used to another language i.e change the label and text block texts to another language. For this I need to use a sqlite database. I have created the table and need to switch in-between the languages when I select the option from the combo box. Can anyone give any suggestions on that I could do. Also this is in mvvm.

Comment: the sqlite database contains both the languages along with the label and button names used.

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx) is pretty good article about localization in WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this points you in right direction? Complete with instructions and WPF example project here
http://www.mesta-automation.com/multilanguage-applications-with-c-with-database-support/

Screencap from example itself:
[image: notfound]

Comment: this is kind of helpful. Thank you.